# Cual es la utilidad del parametro de salida en c#

Tags: c#

Estoy aprendiendo a usar parametros de salida, pero no encuentro sentido usarlo, por ejemplo el siguiente ejemplo usa "out"

```
class Listing
{
    Main()
    {
        int entero;
        Listing listing=new Listing();
        listing.callMethod(out entero);
        s.c.wl(entero);
    }

    void callMethod(out int integer)
    {
        integer=9;
    }
}
```

pero sin usar "out" podria usar el siguiente codigo

```
class Listing{

    Main()
    {
        int entero;
        Listing listing=new Listing();
        listing.callMethod();
        system.console.wl(entero);
    }

    void callMethod()
    {
        entero=9;
    }
}
```

no veo la utilidad de usar un parametro de salida "out", supuestamente se usa para devolver varios resultados, pero cada funcion solo debe hacer una sola cosa y por lo tanto debe devolver solo un resultado, entonces out no tendria sentido?

Comment: ayuda entender el codigo si la agregas identacion

Comment: el segundo metodo descripto aca no compila

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes razón en que es mejor que una función devuelva una sola cosa, más eso no significa necesariamente que solo requiera tener un retorno.
Muchos son los casos, por ejemplo, en los que un resultado está condicionado por la disponibilidad de ciertos datos o servicio (base de datos, accesibilidad a internet, etc). En esos casos no es raro que se haga una función que regrese tanto un resultado estándar como un valor que indique si la operación fallo o resulto exitosa.

Tal es el caso de las funciones TryParse que proveen una interfaz más segura que las correspondientes funciones Parse, pues integran un mecanismo directo para revisar si el usuario ingresó un valor correcto, en lugar de simplemente lanzar una excepción.

```
string val1 = "1234";
string val2 = "abc";
int a, b;

if (int.TryParse(val1, out a))
{
    System.Console.WriteLine($"El valor en val1 es: {a}");
}
else
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("val1 no almacena un número");
}

if (int.TryParse(val1, out b))
{
    System.Console.WriteLine($"El valor en val2 es: {b}");
}
else
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("val2 no almacena un número");
}
```

El resultado de lo anterior sería:

```
El valor de val1 es: 1234
val2 no almacena un número
```

Claro, en algunas condiciones las variables tienen valores válidos y valores inválidos muy bien definidos, por lo que puedes permitirte usar un solo valor de retorno y usar uno de sus valores inválidos como señal de error. El problema es que no siempre es tan fácil delimitar que valores serán válidos para nuestra variable y cuales no, por lo que la anterior sigue siendo la solución más general y elegante al problema del valor de retorno+comprobación de éxito.

Otro caso de uso común de los parámetros de salida es asegurarte de que el valor de retorno de la función no sea ignorado bajo ninguna circunstancia. En una función normal siempre podemos elegir no almacenar el valor de retorno en ningún lado:

```
int func() { return 1; }
...
func(); // Se descarta el retorno
```

Si un programador delibera que el valor de retorno es vital, puede evitar que sus compañeros olviden guardarlo mediante los parámetros out:

```
void func(out int salida) { salida = 1; }
...
func(out variable);
```

De esta forma, se producirá un error de compilación si alguien no pasa una variable asignable, obligando en la práctica a siempre guardar el valor de retorno.

Answer (score 1):

Es correcto lo que planteas, tener un parametro de `out` solo para un valor puede que no sea necesario en todos los caso

En tu caso en concreto el segundo codigo no compila, ya que desde el metodo `callMethod()` no tienes acceso a esa variable sino cambias de ambito, como ser

```
class Listing{

    int entero;

    Main()
    {
        Listing listing=new Listing();
        listing.callMethod();
        system.console.wl(entero);
    }

    void callMethod()
    {
        entero=9;
    }
}
```

como observaras la varible `entero` esta a nivel de la clase `Listing` por fuera de los metodos

Otra alternativa aun mejor es usar el `return` para devolver solo una respuesta y no tener que definir `variables globales`, algo como ser

```
class Listing{

    Main()
    {
        Listing listing=new Listing();
        int entero = listing.callMethod();

        system.console.wl(entero);
    }

    int callMethod()
    {
        return 9;
    }
}
```

[return (Referencia de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/return)

---

Ademas el titulo que has puesto no tiene relacion con la explicacion que detallas

La cantidad de parametros puede ser muchos, pero por lo general hay ciertas reglas cuando exceden un cierto numero ya que hara la applicacion inmantenible, por eso se suele pasar a clases definiendo objeto con propiedades